# CodeIgniter 3 controller methods not working when running in sub-directory

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am currently building a new sub-system for a client that will run on a sub-directory like https://example.com/new-subsystem.

Their existing website was native/hard-coded PHP so I have to create a new folder on the root and put the CodeIgniter 3 Framework there. I configured the base_url and voila! It is working fine.

Now the problem is when I try to create a new method inside the controller, it returns error 404 that it seems like that the server is trying to handle the request literally and not let CodeIgniter handle it.

**Example**

When I try to access https://example.com/new-subsystem, it is working fine.

But when I try to access https://example.com/new-subsystem/test it will show Error 404 and seems like the server is trying to find another folder instead. Here is the actual `route.php`, `config.php`, `controller` which I believe that the problem is not on these three.

*routes.php*

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'lockdown';
$route['test'] = 'lockdown/test';
```

*config.php*

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/project-lockdown/tutorials/';
```

*Lockdown.php (Controller)*

```
    class Lockdown extends CI_Controller {
        public function index()
        {
            // This is working by default. It shows on http://localhost/project-lockdown/tutorials/
            echo "Hello World!"
        }
        public function test(){
        // This should show on http://localhost/project-lockdown/tutorials/test
            echo "Hello, this is a test method and it is not working. Error 404 is shown!";
        }
    }
```

**Main Question:**
How to tell the server that I want CodeIgniter to handle the rest of the request that is thrown under http://localhost/project-lockdown/tutorials/(controller)/(method) and not take it literally.

For now, I am stuck here and still trying to find a solution to it across the internet and can find a thing. I am no `.htaccess` guy so I think this has something to with the `.htaccess` magic or something (which I am trying to learn now).

Any help would be appreciated. This problem will not occur if I just throw in CodeIgniter on the root folder.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you forgot to remove index.php from the URL. So that you need to append index.php in the URL to access your controller/method. Try with -  http://localhost/project-lockdown/tutorials/index.php/(controller)/(method)

Comment: Hi @AlokMali, fantastic! It worked I never thought of that. Now I think I need .htaccess to handle the removal of the index.php. Thank you!

Comment: All is working now @AlokMali, Cannot thank you enough for that. I now removed the index.php on .htaccess and It is working now! Thanks again man. Can you post it as answer and I will accept it?

Comment: You are most welcome brother.

Comment: I have added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to append index.php in the URL to access your controller/method. Try with -

`localhost/project-lockdown/tutorials/index.php/(controller)/`

You can remove `index.php` by rewriting some rules in `.htaccess` file.

Comment: This solution worked. Funny how I missed this one. I wrote the rules to instead remove the index.php and set the site_url at the config to empty. Working now. Thank you brother.